# Transform XHTML article to Docbook

Tags: html, pdf, xhtml, docbook

I need to transform some article about information technologies from format XHTML or HTML in to format Docbook. Then i need to transform the Docbook format in to pdf. But i have got a problem with the first sentence. I dont now how to transform XHTML/HTML to Docbook. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> transform some article about information technologies from format
>   XHTML or HTML in to format Docbook.

This is kind of doing the reverse of DocBook XSL transformation. Normally, we convert the DocBook xml source files to outputs like xhtml, or pdf. Here, you were asked to convert a given xhtml article in to DocBook xml format.

There are some tools available to do this. One example is [DocBook Doclet](http://www.michael-a-fuchs.de/).

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, you can use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) and do:

```
pandoc -f html -t docbook input.html
```

alternatively:

I finally found the XSLT to do XHTML to DocBook. The Internet WayBackMachine had a [backup](http://web.archive.org/web/20040306154513/http://docbook.org/wiki/moin.cgi/Html2DocBook) of the HTML2DocBook wiki page which cannot be found anymore on wiki.docbook.org. So in case the waybackmachine stops working or something, here you go.

Note that the output uses bridgeheads instead of section/title's.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"  
                xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
                xmlns:saxon="http://icl.com/saxon" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl fo html saxon"> 

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/> 
<xsl:param name="filename"></xsl:param>  
<xsl:param name="prefix">wb</xsl:param> 
<xsl:param name="graphics_location">file:///epicuser/AISolutions/graphics/AIWorkbench/</xsl:param> 

<!-- Main block-level conversions --> 
<xsl:template match="html:html"> 
 <xsl:apply-templates select="html:body"/> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- This template converts each HTML file encountered into a DocBook  
     section.  For a title, it selects the first h1 element --> 
<xsl:template match="html:body"> 
 <section> 
  <xsl:if test="$filename != ''"> 
   <xsl:attribute name="id"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$prefix"/> 
    <xsl:text>_</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($filename,' ()','__')"/> 
   </xsl:attribute> 
  </xsl:if> 
  <title> 
   <xsl:value-of select=".//html:h1[1] 
                         |.//html:h2[1] 
                         |.//html:h3[1]"/> 
  </title> 
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/> 
 </section> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- This template matches on all HTML header items and makes them into  
     bridgeheads. It attempts to assign an ID to each bridgehead by looking  
     for a named anchor as a child of the header or as the immediate preceding 
     or following sibling --> 
<xsl:template match="html:h1 
              |html:h2 
              |html:h3 
              |html:h4 
              |html:h5 
              |html:h6"> 
 <bridgehead> 
  <xsl:choose> 
   <xsl:when test="count(html:a/@name)"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="id"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="html:a/@name"/> 
    </xsl:attribute> 
   </xsl:when> 
   <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::* = preceding-sibling::html:a[@name != '']"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="id"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix,preceding-sibling::html:a[1]/@name)"/> 
    </xsl:attribute> 
   </xsl:when> 
   <xsl:when test="following-sibling::* = following-sibling::html:a[@name != '']"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="id"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix,following-sibling::html:a[1]/@name)"/> 
    </xsl:attribute> 
   </xsl:when> 
  </xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </bridgehead> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- These templates perform one-to-one conversions of HTML elements into 
     DocBook elements --> 
<xsl:template match="html:p"> 
<!-- if the paragraph has no text (perhaps only a child <img>), don't  
     make it a para --> 
 <xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:when test="normalize-space(.) = ''"> 
   <xsl:apply-templates/> 
  </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise> 
 <para> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </para> 
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="html:pre"> 
 <programlisting> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </programlisting> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- Hyperlinks --> 
<xsl:template match="html:a[contains(@href,'http://')]" priority="1.5"> 
 <ulink> 
  <xsl:attribute name="url"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@href)"/> 
  </xsl:attribute> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </ulink> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="html:a[contains(@href,'#')]" priority="0.6"> 
 <xref> 
  <xsl:attribute name="linkend"> 
   <xsl:call-template name="make_id"> 
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after(@href,'#')"/> 
   </xsl:call-template> 
  </xsl:attribute> 
 </xref> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="html:a[@href != '']"> 
 <xref> 
  <xsl:attribute name="linkend"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="$prefix"/> 
   <xsl:text>_</xsl:text> 
   <xsl:call-template name="make_id"> 
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@href"/> 
   </xsl:call-template> 
  </xsl:attribute> 
 </xref> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- Need to come up with good template for converting filenames into ID's --> 
<xsl:template name="make_id"> 
 <xsl:param name="string" select="''"/> 
 <xsl:variable name="fixedname"> 
  <xsl:call-template name="get_filename"> 
   <xsl:with-param name="path" select="translate($string,' \()','_/_')"/> 
  </xsl:call-template> 
 </xsl:variable> 
 <xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:when test="contains($fixedname,'.htm')"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($fixedname,'.htm')"/> 
  </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise> 
   <xsl:value-of select="$fixedname"/> 
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="string.subst"> 
 <xsl:param name="string" select="''"/> 
 <xsl:param name="substitute" select="''"/> 
 <xsl:param name="with" select="''"/> 
 <xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:when test="contains($string,$substitute)"> 
   <xsl:variable name="pre" select="substring-before($string,$substitute)"/> 
   <xsl:variable name="post" select="substring-after($string,$substitute)"/> 
   <xsl:call-template name="string.subst"> 
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="concat($pre,$with,$post)"/> 
    <xsl:with-param name="substitute" select="$substitute"/> 
    <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/> 
   </xsl:call-template> 
  </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise> 
   <xsl:value-of select="$string"/> 
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- Images --> 
<!-- Images and image maps --> 
<xsl:template match="html:img"> 
 <xsl:variable name="tag_name"> 
  <xsl:choose> 
   <xsl:when test="boolean(parent::html:p) and  
        boolean(normalize-space(parent::html:p/text()))"> 
    <xsl:text>inlinemediaobject</xsl:text> 
   </xsl:when> 
   <xsl:otherwise>mediaobject</xsl:otherwise> 
  </xsl:choose> 
 </xsl:variable> 
 <xsl:element name="{$tag_name}"> 
  <imageobject> 
   <xsl:call-template name="process.image"/> 
  </imageobject> 
 </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="process.image"> 
 <imagedata> 
<xsl:attribute name="fileref"> 
 <xsl:call-template name="make_absolute"> 
  <xsl:with-param name="filename" select="@src"/> 
 </xsl:call-template> 
</xsl:attribute> 
<xsl:if test="@height != ''"> 
 <xsl:attribute name="depth"> 
  <xsl:value-of select="@height"/> 
 </xsl:attribute> 
</xsl:if> 
<xsl:if test="@width != ''"> 
 <xsl:attribute name="width"> 
  <xsl:value-of select="@width"/> 
 </xsl:attribute> 
</xsl:if> 
 </imagedata> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="make_absolute"> 
 <xsl:param name="filename"/> 
 <xsl:variable name="name_only"> 
  <xsl:call-template name="get_filename"> 
   <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$filename"/> 
  </xsl:call-template> 
 </xsl:variable> 
 <xsl:value-of select="$graphics_location"/><xsl:value-of select="$name_only"/> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="html:ul[count(*) = 0]"> 
 <xsl:message>Matched</xsl:message> 
 <blockquote> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </blockquote> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="get_filename"> 
 <xsl:param name="path"/> 
 <xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:when test="contains($path,'/')"> 
   <xsl:call-template name="get_filename"> 
    <xsl:with-param name="path" select="substring-after($path,'/')"/> 
   </xsl:call-template> 
  </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise> 
   <xsl:value-of select="$path"/> 
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- LIST ELEMENTS --> 
<xsl:template match="html:ul"> 
 <itemizedlist> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </itemizedlist> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="html:ol"> 
 <orderedlist> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </orderedlist> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- This template makes a DocBook variablelist out of an HTML definition list --> 
<xsl:template match="html:dl"> 
 <variablelist> 
  <xsl:for-each select="html:dt"> 
   <varlistentry> 
    <term> 
     <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </term> 
    <listitem> 
     <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::html:dd[1]"/> 
    </listitem> 
   </varlistentry> 
  </xsl:for-each> 
 </variablelist> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="html:dd"> 
 <xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:when test="boolean(html:p)"> 
   <xsl:apply-templates/> 
  </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise> 
   <para> 
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
   </para> 
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="html:li"> 
 <listitem> 
  <xsl:choose> 
   <xsl:when test="count(html:p) = 0"> 
    <para> 
     <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </para> 
   </xsl:when> 
   <xsl:otherwise> 
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
   </xsl:otherwise> 
  </xsl:choose> 
 </listitem> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="*"> 
 <xsl:message>No template for <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> 
 </xsl:message> 
 <xsl:apply-templates/> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="@*"> 
 <xsl:message>No template for <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> 
 </xsl:message> 
 <xsl:apply-templates/> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- inline formatting --> 
<xsl:template match="html:b"> 
 <emphasis role="bold"> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </emphasis> 
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="html:i"> 
 <emphasis> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </emphasis> 
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="html:u"> 
 <citetitle> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </citetitle> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- Ignored elements --> 
<xsl:template match="html:hr"/> 
<xsl:template match="html:h1[1]|html:h2[1]|html:h3[1]" priority="1"/> 
<xsl:template match="html:br"/> 
<xsl:template match="html:p[normalize-space(.) = '' and count(*) = 0]"/> 
<xsl:template match="text()"> 
 <xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:when test="normalize-space(.) = ''"></xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy/></xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- Workbench Hacks --> 
<xsl:template match="html:div[contains(@style,'margin-left: 2em')]"> 
 <blockquote><para> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/></para> 
 </blockquote> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="html:a[@href != ''  
                      and not(boolean(ancestor::html:p|ancestor::html:li))]"  
              priority="1"> 
 <para> 
 <xref> 
  <xsl:attribute name="linkend"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="$prefix"/> 
   <xsl:text>_</xsl:text> 
   <xsl:call-template name="make_id"> 
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@href"/> 
   </xsl:call-template> 
  </xsl:attribute> 
 </xref> 
 </para> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="html:a[contains(@href,'#')  
                    and not(boolean(ancestor::html:p|ancestor::html:li))]"  
              priority="1.1"> 
 <para> 
 <xref> 
  <xsl:attribute name="linkend"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="$prefix"/> 
   <xsl:text>_</xsl:text> 
   <xsl:call-template name="make_id"> 
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after(@href,'#')"/> 
   </xsl:call-template> 
  </xsl:attribute> 
 </xref> 
 </para> 
</xsl:template> 

<!-- Table conversion --> 
<xsl:template match="html:table"> 
<!-- <xsl:variable name="column_count" 
               select="saxon:max(.//html:tr,saxon:expression('count(html:td)'))"/> --> 
 <xsl:variable name="column_count"> 
  <xsl:call-template name="count_columns"> 
   <xsl:with-param name="table" select="."/> 
  </xsl:call-template> 
 </xsl:variable> 
 <informaltable> 
  <tgroup> 
   <xsl:attribute name="cols"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$column_count"/> 
   </xsl:attribute> 
   <xsl:call-template name="generate-colspecs"> 
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$column_count"/> 
   </xsl:call-template> 
   <thead> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="html:tr[1]"/> 
   </thead> 
   <tbody> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="html:tr[position() != 1]"/> 
   </tbody> 
  </tgroup> 
 </informaltable> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="generate-colspecs"> 
 <xsl:param name="count" select="0"/> 
 <xsl:param name="number" select="1"/> 
 <xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:when test="$count &lt; $number"/> 
  <xsl:otherwise> 
   <colspec> 
    <xsl:attribute name="colnum"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="$number"/> 
    </xsl:attribute> 
    <xsl:attribute name="colname"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('col',$number)"/> 
    </xsl:attribute> 
   </colspec> 
   <xsl:call-template name="generate-colspecs"> 
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count"/> 
    <xsl:with-param name="number" select="$number + 1"/> 
   </xsl:call-template> 
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="html:tr"> 
 <row> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </row> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="html:th|html:td"> 
 <xsl:variable name="position" select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/> 
 <entry> 
  <xsl:if test="@colspan &gt; 1"> 
   <xsl:attribute name="namest"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('col',$position)"/> 
   </xsl:attribute> 
   <xsl:attribute name="nameend"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('col',$position + number(@colspan) - 1)"/> 
   </xsl:attribute> 
  </xsl:if> 
  <xsl:if test="@rowspan &gt; 1"> 
   <xsl:attribute name="morerows"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="number(@rowspan) - 1"/> 
   </xsl:attribute> 
  </xsl:if> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </entry> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="html:td_null"> 
 <xsl:apply-templates/> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="count_columns"> 
 <xsl:param name="table" select="."/> 
 <xsl:param name="row" select="$table/html:tr[1]"/> 
 <xsl:param name="max" select="0"/> 
 <xsl:choose>  
  <xsl:when test="local-name($table) != 'table'"> 
   <xsl:message>Attempting to count columns on a non-table element</xsl:message> 
  </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:when test="local-name($row) != 'tr'"> 
   <xsl:message>Row parameter is not a valid row</xsl:message> 
  </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise> 
   <!-- Count cells in the current row --> 
   <xsl:variable name="current_count"> 
    <xsl:call-template name="count_cells"> 
     <xsl:with-param name="cell" select="$row/html:td[1]|$row/html:th[1]"/> 
    </xsl:call-template> 
   </xsl:variable> 
   <!-- Check for the maximum value of $current_count and $max --> 
   <xsl:variable name="new_max"> 
    <xsl:choose> 
     <xsl:when test="$current_count &gt; $max"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="number($current_count)"/> 
     </xsl:when> 
     <xsl:otherwise> 
      <xsl:value-of select="number($max)"/> 
     </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
   </xsl:variable> 
   <!-- If this is the last row, return $max, otherwise continue --> 
   <xsl:choose> 
    <xsl:when test="count($row/following-sibling::html:tr) = 0"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="$new_max"/> 
    </xsl:when> 
    <xsl:otherwise> 
     <xsl:call-template name="count_columns"> 
      <xsl:with-param name="table" select="$table"/> 
      <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row/following-sibling::html:tr"/> 
      <xsl:with-param name="max" select="$new_max"/> 
     </xsl:call-template> 
    </xsl:otherwise> 
   </xsl:choose> 
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="count_cells"> 
 <xsl:param name="cell"/> 
 <xsl:param name="count" select="0"/> 
 <xsl:variable name="new_count"> 
  <xsl:choose> 
   <xsl:when test="$cell/@colspan &gt; 1"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="number($cell/@colspan) + number($count)"/> 
   </xsl:when> 
   <xsl:otherwise> 
    <xsl:value-of select="number('1') + number($count)"/> 
   </xsl:otherwise> 
  </xsl:choose> 
 </xsl:variable> 
 <xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:when test="count($cell/following-sibling::*) &gt; 0"> 
   <xsl:call-template name="count_cells"> 
    <xsl:with-param name="cell" 
                    select="$cell/following-sibling::*[1]"/> 
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$new_count"/> 
   </xsl:call-template> 
  </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise> 
   <xsl:value-of select="$new_count"/> 
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason you need to convert to docbook before converting to PDF?

You might look into DocRaptor, if you'd rather convert from HTML straight to PDF. DocRaptor allows you to [convert HTML to PDF](http://docraptor.com/) with a simple HTTP POST to its servers.

It's easy to use and they've got different code examples listed here:

http://docraptor.com/examples