# How do I use xslt to convert XHTML to DocBook XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, apache-fop, docbook

I've found this answer:

[Transform XHTML article to Docbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189155/transform-xhtml-article-to-docbook)

but there's no indication of what the FOP command should look like. I even went to the wayback machine link to see the original page, but no joy.

The fop.bat script on my Win 10 machine doesn't appear to have a command line that allows xhtml input or DocBook xml output.

Comment: FOP takes as input an FO file; alternatively, it can be given an XML file and an XSL stylesheet that produces the FO elements. If you have a DocBook XML file, you need a stylesheet that transforms it into an FO file, for example [DocBook XSL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/).

Comment: Where does the reference question mention FOP?

Comment: The [Apache Formatting Objects Processor](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) converts XSL-FO (.fo) files to PDF files. Is used for converting DocBook to XML-FO which then is converted to XHTML or PDF. It is not used for converting XHTML into DocBook.

Comment: Thanks, all! I guess I'm not familiar enough with the tools yet. I'll take a look at XSL-FO.